# Filter a Liquid/Jekyll array with != logic?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll to construct a site and am trying to create a 'Recent Posts' array at the end of every post using Liquid logic.

I want this array to consist of all posts **except** the post of the page you're currently on.

So, I started with:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:2 %}
  {% if post.title != page.title %}
    //render the post
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, except that my `limit: 2` is causing issue. Since Liquid limits **before** the `if` logic, if it indeed encounters the post whose title equals the current page's title, it will (correctly) not render it, but it will consider the limit "satisfied" - and I end up with only 1 related post instead of 2.

Next I tried creating my own array of posts:

```
{% assign currentPostTitle = "{{ page.title }}" %}
{% assign allPostsButThisOne = (site.posts | where: "title" != currentPostTitle) %}

{% for post in allPostsButThisOne limit:2 %}
  //render the post          
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work because I can't get the `where` filter to accept the `!=` logic.

How can I successfully get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter :

```
{% assign maxCount = 2 %}
{% assign count = 0 %}
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.title != page.title and count < maxCount %}
    {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I needed - a fresh way to think about solving the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you only miss on this code:

```
{% assign allPostsButThisOne = (site.posts | where: "title" != currentPostTitle) %}
```

You my try to use [`contains`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/operators#contains) with [`unless`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/control-flow-tags#unless)

```
{% assign allPostsButThisOne = (site.posts | where_exp:"post", "unless post.title contains currentPostTitle") %}
```

Comment: That syntax is wrong. A standard way of doing that is:

`
{% assign allPostsButThisOne = (site.posts | where_exp: "item", "item.title != 'currentPostTitle'") %}
`

Comment: inigomedina's syntax almost worked for me, I just needed to remove the parentheses